# Largest prime factor-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the largest prime factor of a given number (600851475143) using Python. I've made the following code, but I don't know what is wrong and whether I am using right code Please help find my mistake and improve it.

```
import math
def t(x):

    l=[] 

    for i in range(1,int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if x%i==0:

            l.append(i)
    return l




def check(y):
    for i in range(2,1+y/2):
        if y%i==0:
           return 'this is not prime'
    return 'ya'



print t(600851475143)    
print check(486847)
```

Comment: This is not efficient. If I were you, I would use a Eratosthenes' sieve to generate a list of primes up to the desired number, and then iterate through them in reverse (as you want the largest one) to check if your number is evenly divisible by it.

Comment: @pzp but that would require a lot of memory

Comment: @jlhonora That's true. At the very least OP should iterate in reverse and should use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.

Comment: @pzp agreed, that's a good approach

Comment: I am new to programming and don't know much about algorithms and Eratosthenes' sieve so can you tell me what is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close.  Your `check()` is returning before you want it to.  You want:

```
def check(y):
    for i in range(2,1+y/2):
        if y%i==0:
           return 'this is not prime'
    return 'ya'
```

This will wait until you've check all the numbers < `y` before returning false.  Right now, it checks 2, then returns either true or false.

Also `t()` is returning all factors, rather than the greatest factor.  For just the greatest factor (assuming there is one), you want `return l[-1]`

**EDIT:**
Ok, I think I get what you're going for.  By using this `t()` and `check()`, you can get the largest prime by with:

```
def t(x):
    l=[] 
    for i in range(1,int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if x%i==0:
            l.append(i)
    return l
    #Notice, return list of all factors

def check(y):
    for i in range(2,1+y/2):
        if y%i==0:
           return False
    return True

number_to_check = 92873465
prime_factors = []
for factor in t(number_to_check): # Iterate through factors returned from t()
    if check(factor):
         prime_factors.append(factor)

print "Largest Prime Factor: " + prime_factors[-1]
```

Comment: thanks #Will I myself just figured it out but what about the prime factor

Comment: but the answer which I am calculating is not correct according to website

Comment: You should have `t()` fill a list with all the factors of a number, then `check()` if each one is prime.

Comment: I tried that but the number is so big that the shell sows runtime error so i reduced the factors

Comment: Is calculating factors till the sqrt of number correct approach

Comment: @siddharthyadav, you will want a much more efficient  approach if you have very large numbers

Comment: I’ve never seen this checking up to square root strategy, I was assuming you knew the reason for that.  I'm assuming `t()` was what you meant by it, you may need to check your theory here.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham I started python(also programming) 1.5months earlier and don't know much algorithms so can you help me with more efficient approach

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that everything you're adding to the list is actually a prime

```
    for i in range(1,int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if (x % i) != 0:
            continue
        if check(i):
            l.append(i)
```

Then, pop the last (largest) element of the list:

```
    return l.pop()
```

You can also check up to the square root:

```
def check(y):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(y))):
        if (y % i) == 0:
           return False
    return True
```

Here's a slightly modified version that iterates backwards (as suggested by pzp), and returns as soon as a prime is found:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math
def t(x):
    for i in xrange(int(math.sqrt(x)), 1, -1):
        if (x % i) != 0:
            continue
        if check(i):
            return i
    return None

def check(y):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(y))):
        if (y % i) == 0:
           return False
    return True

print t(600851475143)
print check(6857)
```